# Left hand side of assignment must a variable, property, or index

Tags: c#

When I input this code into Visual Studio I get told that:

> the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property, or
>   index

but the value I am entering is a subroutine that returns a value, and this normally works in other comparison parts of the code:

```
   static void LuckEvent()
   {
        if (DiceRoll() = 1)
        {

        }       
        if (DiceRoll() < 1 && 4 > DiceRoll())
        {

        }
        if (DiceRoll() = 4)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need two equal signs `==` when you are testing the value.  If you use only one equal sign you are doing an assignment.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you happen to be a VB or VBA programmer? If so, then it is entirely understandable that you confused these things.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and I am neither. I'm just a student who's only recently been involved in programming, I'm mainly a Python programmer.

Comment: I have been writing C# since the original .NET betas and I still manage to make this mistake at least once a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax

```
if (DiceRoll() = 1)
```

should be

```
if (DiceRoll() == 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

= is the assignment operator 
== is the equality operator

```
        static void LuckEvent()
        {
            if (DiceRoll() == 1)
            {

            }       
            if (DiceRoll() < 1 && 4 > DiceRoll())
            {

            }
            if (DiceRoll() == 4)
            {

            }
        }
```